# keyword WITH for two queries

Tags: sql-server, subquery, with-statement

I want to do this :

```
WITH temp (f1, f2, ...)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 1>
    SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 2>
END
```

but SQL Server raise error...
is there any solution to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple CTEs separated with a comma `,` something like this.....

```
;WITH temp1 (f1, f2, ...) AS 
(    
    SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 1>
 ), 
 Temp2 (f1, f2, ...) AS
 (
    SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 2>
  )
SELECT ......
```

Or if you want combine results returned from both queries you can do this in One cte something like this....

```
;WITH temp1 (f1, f2, ...) AS 
(    
  SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 1>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 2>
 )
SELECT ......
```

Comment: NO, I want : ;WITH temp1 (f1, f2, ...) AS 
(    
  SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 1>
  --UNION ALL
  --SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 2>
 )
SELECT ...... and SELECT ......

Comment: One CTE or Two CTEs if defined together must me consumed in the following statement (UPDATE/INSERT/SELECT). These two following selects you have shown in your comment can be nested or Union but you cannot have to separate selects. This is by syntax , if you do need to write a query like and later select twice from that, then you have only two choices , a Temp table or a Table variable. but not cte . I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `UNION ALL` to merge both datasets

```
WITH temp AS (select * from mytable)
   SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 1>
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM temp WHERE <condition 2>
```

Comment: there is no such syntax `WITH` with `BEGIN..END` block, atleast in sql server :)

Comment: my question is what M.Ali said... What solution can we have instead ?

Comment: yeah i just rewrote it